# How to prevent browser from loading images in mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, gatsby

I have a header on the website that looks like this in desktop view:

[image]

but on the mobile version, the photo is set to display: none;

[image]

but yet the audit showed that the browser still loaded it anyway!

so I tried to `display: none;` the father div and still loaded,

is there's a way to stop the browser from loading it?

Comment: Does the image load in the networks tab?

Comment: answer here: https://swimburger.net/blog/web/web-performance-prevent-wasteful-hidden-image-requests

Comment: @Rust yes, and on the audit tab too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use your picture as a background-image. 
It will only be loaded if the media-queries are accepted, so for mobile devices the picture don't load and for desktop versions the picture will load.

The downside to this is that Google won't index your picture in for example Google Images but if your picture doesn't have a benefit for the user/text it isn't bad.

---

The other option is that you use

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="your-desktop-picture.jpg">
  <source srcset="your-mobile-picture.jpg">
  <img src="fallback-for-old-browsers.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

You can use picture to choose between different images, your mobile-picture could also be one pixel big, but it is important to have one, so the browser won't choose the desktop picture.

---

In summary i would recommend the solution with the css media-queries because it's easier and your picture isn't necassary for text understanding.

Comment: I know that my picture isn't necessary for text but that was a cool thing to learn! can i use this to just show different img size for every screen ? that'd be really cool i think

Comment: Yes it's possible and I would recommend it for faster load times. You could also try the attribute `sizes`. And if you use different type of images like "webp"-images and "jpg" as fallback I would also recommend to use this

Answer (score 2):

The browser isn't aware of the CSS and that the image will not be shown for mobile when it is parsing the the DOM tree.

You need to tell the browser the image should only be loaded for a certain size using dom elements. You can use the `sizes` attribute to tell the browser on which size the image should be loaded.

```
                            the media query   image display size
                                     v             v
<img src="./kitten.jpg" sizes="(min-width: 768px) 700px" />
```

> Note: The sizes attribute is just telling the browser the image
>   size and not actually resizing the image. You will still need to keep
>   any CSS related to the image.

Comment: I added min-width: 768px and still showed at 767px and lower!

Comment: @A.Atiyah Make sure that cache is cleared... If the browser finds a caches image, it will load the image from the cache anyway